# How to redirect both secure and non-secure root to a login page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

***My goal***: If a user navigates to a root url (http://localhost), or a secure version of a root url (https://localhost), they will then be redirected to a secure version of the login page (https://localhost/login/index.html).

***My issue***: The redirect for the non-secured root is working correctly, by navigating to the url described above (http://localhost redirects to https://localhost/login/index.html), but the secured version does not work, I instead receive a 404 error from apache.

I'm attempting to do this through using the Apache RewriteEngine in my httpd.conf file in Apache. What I have is:

```
#Turn on redirection
RewriteEngine On

# IF someone is trying to access the root directory
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(https://%{HTTP_HOST})?$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(http://%{HTTP_HOST})?$

# Redirect them to the login screen via SSL
RewriteRule ^/$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/login/index.html [R=301]
```

The above config is supposed to work with the following logic:

```
if ( address == SERVER_ROOT ){
    redirectToLoginPageWithSSL();
} else if ( address == HTTPS_SERVER_ROOT ){
    redirectToLoginPageWithSSL();
}
```

I've searched around on Google/SO, and have found many answers on how to redirect a root to a different page, but can't seem to find anything on how to redirect a secured root to a different page.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're rules are in the httpd.conf file, make sure the rules are a part of the SSL vhost *and* non-SSL vhost. They are going to be different and have different configuration containers. You can't match against SSL requests in the non-SSL configuration block. Additionally, the `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable is **only** the host, no "http://".

So the only rule you need is:

```
#Turn on redirection
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect them to the login screen via SSL
RewriteRule ^/$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/login/index.html [R=301]
```

in both the SSL and non-SSL configuration/vhost containers. It'll be in something that looks like:

```
<VirtualHost (something)>


</VirtualHost>
```

Another way you can do this is in an htaccess file. Assuming that both your SSL and non-SSL sites point to the *same document root* folder, you can use a single htaccess file to affect both. And all you'd need is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/login/index.html [L,R=301]
```

Note that there is no leading `/` in the rule regex for rules in an htaccess file.